# How to get results from a Jira Rest API request?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postman, jira-rest-api

I want to be able to take JSON data that I get from a RestRequest to the Jira Rest API and put that information into a graph. However I am unable to even write the response data to the console. I know what information I should be getting because when I make the request in postman I get a response with the expected data in it.

Here is my code that I generated directly from postman to hopefully replicate what postman is doing inside of visual studio.

How do I get the results from the Jira Rest API request that I am making?

I'm thinking it is a relatively simple fix, but I am just not that familiar with interacting with this API.

```
var client = new RestClient(myCompanyURL/rest/api/2/issue/NID-3.json");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            //request.AddHeader("postman-token", "tokenGeneratedFromPostman");
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic  myEncodedInformation");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"fields\": {\n\t\t\"project\":\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"key\":\"NID\"\n\t\t},\n\t\t\"summary\": \"TEST\",\n\t\t\"description\": \"Test Description\",\n\t\t\"issuetype\": {\n\t\t\t\"name\":\"Task\"\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to send JSON in the body, but your request method is GET.

Comment: my issue is that this code is generated directly from postman (not the Console.Writeline(response);)  But inside of Postman this returns all the information about the "NID-3" issue. Wouldn't it make sense that writing the response to the console would display the same information that I get from postman?